What Vin should I use to create a PI controller to stabilize an error of a signal?

In this design I am making an incubator, in such a way that a temperature sensor sends a voltage to two comparators that decide whether a fan or a light bulb should be turned on to always maintain the desired temperature.
I need to implement the Pi controller that we see above in the image but I don't know how, that is, in which part of the circuit should I add it, with what Vin and where would its Vout go?

Datasheet on the sensor, please. I see a resistor there. But you say "voltage." I suppose the divider network might answer my question. But I'd very much rather just see the datasheet for myself. Also, I see LEDs. I'd like a clear expression about what those are supposed to indicate. I don't want to guess about it. Finally, what's the output driving. Not approximately. But exactly what is it? Datasheets for that, as well. (I know it drives a heater and a fan. But details matter. No guessing.) Everything is about the inputs and the outputs. The middle parts are always easier. Even PI.

It sounds more like you should be implementing a bang-bang controller.

You can't wire the outputs of 2 opamps directly together like that. You need to sum them or use some sort of resistor-divider arrangement.
